# Multiple visual text cursors in QPlainTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, text-editor, qtextcursor

In [Sublime Text](https://www.nobledesktop.com/blog/multiple-text-cursors-with-arrow-keys-in-sublime-text), if you hold control while clicking, you can add another cursor to the document, allowing you to type and edit in multiple places at once. I'm trying to recreate this with Qt's QPlainTextEdit. The logic seems pretty simple...

- On <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd>, create and store a new cursor at location of the click
- Draw all cursors
- When any key events happen, make sure the other cursors also receive them

However, it seems that in order to do these things, I have to understand exactly how QPlainTextEdit works, and while I have a loose understanding, I find the source to be very dense and difficult to navigate.

While this feature is very important to me, I can't afford to spend a month on it. I don't know how to reasonably proceed. Is there some open source text editor built with Qt that has this feature? Can I in fact implement it without thoroughly understanding how QPlainTextEdit works? Is there some other solution I have not considered? I thought this would be trivial, or at the very least someone might have solved it before, but that doesn't appear to be the case. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there some open source text editor built with Qt that has this feature?

QtCreator is open-source ([source code](https://github.com/qt-creator/qt-creator)) and has partial multiple-cursor functionality. While it does not support Ctrl+Click to add a new cursor, you can do Shift+Alt+DownArrow to add a cursor to the following line (same column), like in SublimeText, and then insert text to all the lines at once.

It seems implemented in their class [TextEditorWidget](https://github.com/qt-creator/qt-creator/blob/79383202916a0b73301e012269a995aa9219e34d/src/plugins/texteditor/texteditor.cpp), which inherits QPlainTextEdit and reimplements plenty of its virtual methods. I don't exactly know how they implemented the multi-cursor functionality, but probably looking at the code of TextEditorWidget can give hints.

However, keep in mind that QtCreator does not have full multi-cursor functionality like in Sublime Text or CLion: the mutliple cursors are necessarily in the same column, and you cannot move the multiple cursors left/right. For example something I often do in Sublime is multiple selection at the beginning of lines, followed by Ctrl+RightArrow to jump all cursors "one word to the right". You cannot do that in QtCreator as of August 2020.

There is an open feature request for having true multiple-cursor functionality in QtCreator:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-16013

Comment: I gues it's right way. But i don't shure what he need reimplement TextEditorWidget. I gues he must write his own Widget. It's very simple if we know Canvas techniques. Or use workaround with wrap TextEditorWidget,

Comment: One could just copy/past the `TextEditorWidget` (and strip of the unneeded parts) if you take the license conditions into account.

Answer (score 1):

> However, it seems that in order to do these things, I have to
> understand exactly how QPlainTextEdit works, and while I have a loose
> understanding, I find the source to be very dense and difficult to
> navigate.

To some extent, but not a lot. Once you get the cursor positions, you know the positions in the document where text needs to be inserted. QTextEdit already supports multiple cursor positions:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-cursor.html

> Rich text documents can have multiple cursors associated with them,
> and each of these contains information about their position in the
> document and any selections that they may hold. This cursor-based
> paradigm makes common operations, such as cutting and pasting text,
> simple to implement programmatically, yet it also allows more complex
> editing operations to be performed on the document.

and

> Multiple Cursors
>
> Multiple cursors can be used to simultaneously edit the same document,
> although only one will be visible to the user in a QTextEdit widget.
> The QTextDocument ensures that each cursor writes text correctly and
> does not interfere with any of the others.

Since this feature already exists, it may not be as difficult as thought to read the documentation and implement the feature.

As QPlainTextEdit is implemented by using most of the tech behind QTextEdit and QTextDocument, maybe it will meet your requirements.

Comment: 1. How should one display multiple _visible_ cursors? Without, it isn't clear to the user at which places text will be inserted. Would this be possible without changing the internals of `QPlainTextEdit`?

Comment: 2. How should one capture all the editing events (including shortcuts and cursor moves) to replicate it for the different cursors?

Comment: @m7913d Yes, you would have to write some code of your own for representing the cursor visually. The point I'm making is that everything else is already taken care of. Regarding capturing editing events, after you place the cursor, the user can behave as if he would if he was just operating one cursor and the changes happen for both cursors automatically. You should read the documentation, and open a new question for any specific issues, as it will become unwieldy to try to answer everything here.

Comment: I don't think the changes will automatically happen for both cursors when multiple cursors are created. It is not stated in the docs, is it?

Comment: Shouldn't we close the question if it is too broad, instead of answering only a small subset of it?